# Get current date values to own hours

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I get values to MySql database everyday at each hour.
I got site with highcharts, but I cant get it to work.

I need to get current day values from MySql organized to own hours.

Here is my Highcharts code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "Today's Values"
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Values by Hour'
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },                  
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['12AM', '1AM', '2AM', '3AM', '4AM', '5AM', 
                            '6AM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM','12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', 
                            '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Values'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2,
                        crosshairs: true,
                        shared: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '$' + this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        spline: {
                            marker: {
                                radius: 4,
                                lineColor: '#666666',
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Values',
                        data: [
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                    }]
                });                             
            });


</script>
```

Here is pic from MySql database how it looks like

[chart](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/39/chartlp.png)

So, I need all values from MySql categorized to own hours at chart.
It should count values + show it at own category, any idea how to do this?

Im stuck with this beacause I dont know how to do this.

Comment: _I need to get current day values from MySql organized to own hours_

  This is a simple query, select values from current day and group by hour... what's the trouble?? the query or put the result into the chart??

Comment: It's all about the SQL query and JSON encode provide more code and DB structure maybe we can help more :)

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familiar with article about preprocessing data form MySQL http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database

You should export your data from php as JSON, then if you would like you use categories for xAxis, you need to parse your JSON and push appropaite data to correct place.Similar with data points in series.